# How to use extract shortcode in loop?

Tags: posts, loop, shortcode, gallery

Actually I need to gallery in any new post so i use shortcode for making gallery for every new post. I use images and videos in slider. problem is that I have custom html slider need to convert dynamic. so how to extract shortcode and use images and videos in `<li></li>`tag?

Comment: What exactly do you want? Different output for all galleries? Some galleries? Different gallery-like shortcode?

Comment: every gallery are different for new post i created custom meta box for uploading images through plugin. whose automatically generate shortcode for images. but now i confuse how to use shortcode in wordpress loop to implement in html slider.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
echo do_shortcode('[your_shortcode attribute1="value" attribute2="another"]');
```

this should fire the shortcode function in PHP